# How to animate the MainWindow itself when it is loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, mainwindow

I am fairly new to wpf.I want to apply a fade animation on the MainWindow as soon as it is displayed on the screen.Is that possible?Please Help me out

Comment: if you'd want to just present a splash screen - there are easier ways :) what's the purpose of what you're doing ?

Comment: The main purpose is to create a window that fades in and then make each and every control fall into their places.:-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can apply `StoryBoard` on window `loaded` event to give a fade look to your window. This should work for you -

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Opacity)"
                                 From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"
                                 AutoReverse="False"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Also you can do it in code behind in window `loaded` event handler if you don't want to do it in XaML -

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1, 
                                    (Duration)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        this.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, animation);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks..This worked perfectly.Can you tell me how to do this using c# code instead of XAML please.?